# NHK Live streaming not available on this browser

Tags: firefox, flash, streaming

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop
Firefox 42.0
Shockwave Flash 11.2.202.548 / 11.2 r202
AMD 64

All I can get from NHK World Live TV streaming (http://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/live/) is:

Live streaming not available on this browser.

RT works fine.
CCTV works fine.

So one assumes it's an NHK problem?

Anyone else have this problem? Does NHK work for you?. Is it just me?

Comment: Does not work in Chrome either.

Comment: They are doing really funky browser and feature checking it seems: http://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/en/live/javascripts/nw_live_player.js - Very friendly: "case "Linux" → error. Simple user agent faking doesn't seem to help, but some custom script might. Think Greasemonkey.

Comment: You should try to contact them over what @TBR said - the `if Linux: error` thing in their code is just *wrong*.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in my comment they do weird checking and error out in case of Linux.

Some digging through the JavaScript finds a nice URL: http://www3.nhk.or.jp/nhkworld/app/tv/hlslive_tv.xml -- the URLs listed there can be fed to VLC and play just fine. Second from the top labelled 'wstream' seems to be what you are looking for.

- Open VLC
- press [ctrl-n] 'or' Menu *media*, *open network stream*
- enter URL: http://web-cache.stream.ne.jp/www11/nhkworld-tv/global/222714/live_tv.m3u8 (at least that's what I get right now from the above list)
- press play, wait
- …
- profit!